# searching multiple columns for data

Tags: excel, search, multiple-columns, excel-2007

I am using excel 2007.
I am trying to search for a name in one column then use that row to see if that project is finished or in progress (and take only in progress projects) in another column, then also search for the highest priority on the sheet associated with an open project and under a certain name. I then want to take that data and put it on the cover sheet.

We have 5 different names and are using a priority of 1-5 with 5 being the most important.

[taking the data from this sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtJQp.png)
[image]

[inputting the data on this sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSV0w.png)
[image: uestion]

Comment: Can I use a vlookup for a name, then a hlookup for priority then another for in progress to only the highest priority in progress under a certain name?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

F2:

```
=IF($F$1<>"",VLOOKUP($F$1,$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE),"Import Project")
```

F3:

```
=IF($F$2="In progress",VLOOKUP($F$1,$A$2:$C$6,3,FALSE),"-")
```

**Results:**

[image]